# Contact folder not visible in M365

Tags: outlook, exchangewebservices, microsoft365

I have code using EWS (direct XML, not the managed API) that creates a contact folder in M365. This has been working fine, but recently I discovered that such created folders are not visible in the M365 client unless the option "New Contacts" is turned off (this is labeled "turn off to view contact folders in the previous version of contacts").  Below is the XML that I am supplying to the CreateFolder API. Can anybody tell me what I need to do differently to create a "New" contact folder that is visible by default?

```
<ParentFolderId>
<t:DistinguishedFolderId Id="msgfolderroot"></t:DistinguishedFolderId>
</ParentFolderId>
<Folders>
<t:Folder>
<t:FolderClass>IPF.Contact</t:FolderClass>
<t:DisplayName>JeffTest1</t:DisplayName>
</t:Folder>
</Folders>
```

Comment: In the "New Contacts" feature contact folders (outside of the default) AFAIK aren't included so that's why they get hidden. The feature itself is very sparsely documented you might want to reach out to the email listed in https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-blog/new-improved-contacts-in-outlook-on-the-web/ba-p/3639773  , what I believe you should be doing is switching to using categories where you use contacts folder at the moment. The feature itself is still buggy that haven't fixed the issue where you make changes to the the physical addresses in OWA this doesn't sync.